# Flash Swf clickTag links to url

Tags: flash, hyperlink, clicktag

I need help with linking an swf file on click to an external webpage. What can possibly be wrong with the code below? The swf displays correctly and is clickable but when you click, nothing happens. This is how it looks now when live >> http://www.apprentism.com/test

Comment: Post your code please? are you using the navigateToURL method? or calling a javascript function?

Comment: Make sure there's nothing on top of the button you're setting your event listener to. If there is something on top it'll grab the click event and button will NOT receive one. You can disable MC on top by writing this: topMC.mouseChildren = false; topMC.clickable = false;

Answer (score 0):

Since this is pretty old and you didn't actually post the code on here this is pretty much a random guess...but:

Based on your title (using the name 'clickTag') I'm guessing that the variable you sent to flash when you embedded is 'clickTag', when the standard is actually '**clickTAG**'. Your flash may be looking for a 'clickTAG' var and you're supplying a 'clickTag' one. *It is case sensitive.*